# How does this textbook go from this step to the next? I'm very confused.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Here's a picture detailing the question: [image]

In the second half of the picture where it says

$$
1 = 4 - 1 \cdot (11 - 2 \cdot 4)\\
1 = 3 \cdot 4 - 1 \cdot 11
$$

How did they jump from that first equation to the next? Where'd the $3$ come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have
$$
4-1\cdot(11-2\cdot 4)=4-1\cdot 11+2\cdot 4=3\cdot 4-1\cdot 11
$$
by distributing the $-1$ in front of $(11-2\cdot 4)$ and collecting multiples of $4$.